# How do I get a CSS float to overlap a table?

Tags: html, css, css-float, tablelayout

How do I get a floated element to overlap a table?  It overlaps other divs just fine, but the table seems to force a `clear`.

In my example, the div is overlapped (what I want) but the table below that clears past the floated element (which I don't.)

Example here: http://cssdesk.com/9rZVs.  (IE seems to fry this so I'll paste it here too.)

HTML:

```
<div>
  <span style="float:right;width:40%;">
    content content content content content
    content content content content content
    content content content content content
  </span>
  content content content content...
</div>

<div>
content content content content content 
content content content...
</div>

<table ><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
 width:300px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
span {
 border:2px solid black;
 background-color: #ddd;
 margin: 2px solid gray;
}
div {
 border:2px solid black;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 2px solid gray;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: did you try negative margin??

Answer (score 1):

You can get the functionality you are going for like this:

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <span style="position:absolute;right:0;width:40%;">
    content content content content content
    content content content content content
    content content content content content
  </span>
  content content content content...
</div>
```

See [here](http://cssdesk.com/WpsmT). It appears table display clears any float (from all the tests I ran). I would recommend using the above solution to achieve this result - instead of using floats.

Comment: @Josiah Ruddell: Your example works, but I think your reason is wrong, or else the second <div> would clear too, right?  It seems that it works only with relative positioning, rather than floats...

Comment: @Scott Stafford - yes. This is very interesting. I tried a few things. 1.) making the table display block - no change. 2.) making the div display: table - this made the div behave the same as the table. 3.) adding a clear:both to the div - same result as display: table. It does seem that an element displayed as table clears any float.

Comment: @Josiah, "display: block" is enough. I do not know why you thought otherwise.

Comment: @ANeves - in FireFox this is true. not for webkit (chrome/safari)

Comment: @Josiah Ah, I see... good old browser non-inter-conformity. :) Thanks!

Comment: @Josiah, but take note that your solution would make some content of the table be potentially covered by the div, and not wrap to next line as I think would be intended.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is proper, but giving your table `display: block;` is enough to make it work as you want it to.

You can test this by editing the styles on your example.

Comment: This has no effect in chrome and safari.

Comment: Taking @Josiah 's precious input into account I inspected with chrome. I could find no way to overlap the table with a floated element. I am inclined to say it's a deficiency in the way Chrome handles tables, but I am *way too green* with CSS to say that. I could find nothing in CSS2 that would explain this behaviour. :(